# How to extract Private key Exponent in RSA

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rsa, private-key

When i use `- (void)generateKeyPairRSA` i get these values for public and private key **Public key SecKeyRef: 0x7131000
 Private key SecKeyRef: 0x790b000**.

How to extract n,e,d values from private and public key??

Comment: I want to get private exponent value(D)from private key. any one is having idea on this??

Comment: is generateKeyPairRSA a documented framework method? what does it?

Comment: ya it is cryptoexcerise generatekeypair itself

Comment: generateKeyPairRSA'll generate RSA key pair like public and private key. I would like to extract public Modules(N),public exponent(E) and private Exponent(D) frem genertaed keys.